# Имеет ли смысл создавать конструктор абстрактного класса?

Tags: c++, классы

Имеет ли смысл создавать конструктор абстрактного класса?

Comment: если он нужен - создавайте. Почему бы и нет.

Comment: А если у абстрактного класса есть нестатические поля с нетривиальным конструктором, то конструктор в любом случае будет сгенерирован компилятором.

Answer (score 3):

Возможны ситуации, когда вы *не можете его* **не** *создать*.

Вот такой, как обычно, несколько надуманный пример:

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    Point(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}
};

class Abstract
{
public:
    Abstract():p(1,2){}
    virtual void out() = 0;
protected:
    Point p;
};

class Concrete: public Abstract
{
public:
    void out() override { cout << p.x << "-" << p.y; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Abstract * a = new Concrete;
    a->out();
}
```

Все компилируется, собирается, работает. Закомментируйте строку с `Abstract():p(1,2){}` и попробуйте скомпилировать еще раз...